# getting stock details from yahoo

Tags: charts, yahoo-api, stock

we can get a stock details in yahoo using the following url . but how can i get  stock details using market cap value ,divideend value ,pe ratio ,pro rating instead of sending s=GOOG in the url

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=snd1l1yr

second thing i get chart data using the following url

http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/csv/

but how can i generate graph using the data

please help me ! i spent 5 days to find i cant find the solution . i posted this in some forums i cant get the answer.